# How to close a freeform path with VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a series of freeform shapes copied from a third party application.

These freeform shapes are made of open paths, which cannot be "combined" in PowerPoint (only freeforms made with closed paths can be combined).

The following macro goes through every shape selected, and if it is a freeform, it will create a copy with a closed path and then delete the original shape.

```
    Sub close_poly()


        Dim myshp As Shape
        Dim mycol As String
        Dim mynode As ShapeNode

        Dim myxvals As Variant
        Dim myyvals As Variant

        Dim myxcol As String
        Dim myycol As String

        Dim myffb As FreeformBuilder
        Dim mynewshp As Shape
        Dim myname As String


        For Each myshp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

            With myshp
                If .Type = msoFreeform Then


                    '################ set all line segments to straight
                    '(makes things easier in my specific case but will not work in many)
                    nodecount = 1
                    While nodecount <= .Nodes.Count
                        .Nodes.SetSegmentType nodecount, msoSegmentLine
                        nodecount = nodecount + 1
                    Wend

                    '############## collect coordinates
                     myxcol = ""
                     myycol = ""
                    For Each mynode In myshp.Nodes
                       myxcol = myxcol & mynode.Points(1, 1) & ","
                       myycol = myycol & mynode.Points(1, 2) & ","
                    Next
                    myxcol = Left(myxcol, Len(myxcol) - 1)
                    myycol = Left(myycol, Len(myycol) - 1)

                    myxvals = Split(myxcol, ",")
                    myyvals = Split(myycol, ",")


                    '##############create new freeform


                    Set myffb = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.BuildFreeform(msoEditingAuto, myxvals(0), myyvals(0))
                        For i = 1 To UBound(myxvals)
                            myffb.AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, myxvals(i), myyvals(i)
                        Next i
                        myffb.AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, myxvals(0), myyvals(0)
                    Set mynewshp = myffb.ConvertToShape

                    myshp.PickUp
                    mynewshp.Apply

                    myname = myshp.Name
                    myshp.Delete

                    mynewshp.Name = myname

                End If
            End With


        Next myshp
End Sub
```

Question: is there a simpler way to mimic the program's "close path" function in VBA?

Cheers

Comment: I am guessing it cannot be done since there are no answers. This seems like a major bug on behalf of Microsoft.